# I was not successful in installing Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on my Dell Ubuntu-supported laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation, dell

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on my Dell Ubuntu-supported laptop, which has an Intel(R) Celeron(R) 2955U processor @ 1.4Ghz and 2GB RAM, but I did not succeed. What it told me is `an attempt to configure apt to install additional packages from CD failed`. What I did is I clicked OK, then it told me `installation complete, restart now`. But when it was restarting, it then told me that `...No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!`. Is it that my PC is not among the list of Linux-supported laptops? If it is not, what is that list?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your CD has been incompletely written or improperly burnt. When the installation process is going on, after the partitions are filled with files, there is a step where it checks for your internet connection. If you have one, it will get the updated files from the internet. Else, it would install the locally available files from the CD. It seems that your CD cannot provide these files which means that it is improperly written. Alternately, you can try writing the CD to a pen drive and boot it from there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the installation stopped before it was complete. This can be caused by a defective installation medium. Please try to reinstall Ubuntu with a new installation medium.

This basically means that you will have to recreate/reprepare a new CD/DVD drive or USB stick with a freshly downloaded Ubuntu distribution on it.

Also see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto to verify your downloaded ISO file.

Answer (score 0):

Just about any laptop can run Linux, period. Linux is a very versatile operating system/kernel, and it has native support for most, if not all, hardware. It's just a matter of how well-suited your laptop is for the Linux distribution you're planning to run. In my experience, the latest versions of Ubuntu do not run very well on single-core PCs with less than 2GB of RAM. (My personal hardware recommendations include an Intel Pentium 4 processor (hyperthreaded if allowed by BIOS) or newer (64-bit dual-core or quad-core CPUs work best), 2GB RAM (but 4GB is recommended), and an AMD or NVIDIA graphics card. Your laptop seems to meet the  minimum requirements (or at least my recommended requirements), so no need to worry about that.

I'd like to address a possible issue, however. The CD image you downloaded may have had errors when burned to the disc. I'd suggest re-downloading the image and burning another disc, with a low speed and error prevention/detection if applicable. That should reduce any problems. If you still are receiving this error, reply and we'll figure it out.